# How to get the path of an image in Flutter web?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-image-picker

I'm using [`image_picker`](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) in my Flutter app. When I test my app in Flutter web, it says I can't use `path` parameter in Flutter web.

However, I need to get the path of the image. How to do it?

I googled this, I asked Google Bard and ChatGPT, but didn't find a solution.

I tried changing to using [`image_picker_web`](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker_web) without success finding a solution.

Some of my code:

```
XFile? image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

if (image != null) {
  if ((await File(image.path).length()) > 1000000) {
    return "Oversize";
  } else {
    TaskSnapshot selectedImage = await …(id, File(image.path));

    return await selectedImage.ref.getDownloadURL();
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you need it for? if you want to pass it to `File` constructor it will not work

Comment: @pskink yes, you are right, I want to pass it to the `File` constructor

Comment: so as I said: it will not work on flutter web, instead you have to read your your data using `Stream` api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes in Flutter web you can't work with paths so in my case I used [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) package to pick a file and specified the type of files I needed then I used [mime](https://pub.dev/packages/mime) to get the mime type. My upload file looks like this:

```dart
uploadFiles() async {
  FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
    type: FileType.custom,
    allowMultiple: false,
    allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'pdf', 'doc'],
  );

  if (result != null && result.files.isNotEmpty) {
    final fileBytes = result.files.first.bytes;

    final fileName = result.files.first.name;

    final mime = lookupMimeType('', headerBytes: fileBytes);
    return DocModel(
      name: fileName,
      mimeType: mime,
      fileBytes: fileBytes,
      file: File.fromRawPath(fileBytes!),
    );
  } else {
    // User canceled the picker
    return DocModel();
  }
}
```

Then my `DocModel` looks like this:

```dart
class DocModel {
  int? id;
  String? path;
  String? name;
  File? file;
  String? mimeType;
  Uint8List? fileBytes;

  DocModel({
    this.path,
    this.name,
    this.file,
    this.mimeType,
    this.id,
    this.fileBytes,
  });
}
```

Then to display the image I used `Image.memory(fileBytes from model)`.

Working code can be found here [Github](https://github.com/Chalwe19/flutter_web_file_picker).